# Cabal - could not resolve dependencies error

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, haskell, cabal

I have completed the pioneer program and am writing my own app.  I've created my react front end and now am trying to serialize my smart contract in `Haskell` for a minting policy I wrote.  The problem I am having is I believe I am unable to get the Plutus library installed correctly.  I did a `cabal update` then `cabal init` to get cabal in my program.  I then pretty much copied the cabal configuration from Week05 in the pioneer program with some slight modifications in to my project. See below

```
cabal-version:      2.4
name:               
version:            0.1.0.0
synopsis:           
license:            Apache-2.0
build-type:         Simple

extra-source-files:
   CHANGELOG.md
   README.md

common common-all
    build-depends:    base ^>=4.14.3.0
                , aeson
                , bytestring
                , containers
                , cardano-api
                , data-default
                , plutus-ledger-api
                , plutus-tx-plugin
                , plutus-tx
                , text
                , serialise
                , utilities
default-language: Haskell2010
ghc-options: -Wall -fobject-code -fno-ignore-interface-pragmas
             -fno-omit-interface-pragmas -fno-strictness 
             -fno-spec-constr -fno-specialise -fexpose-all-unfoldings
             -fplugin-opt PlutusTx.Plugin:defer-errors



library 
import:             common-all
hs-source-dirs:     app
exposed-modules:    TC_Contract
```

I have an `app` folder where I have `TC_Contract.hs` so I belivee I have everything I need setup correctly in the cabal configuration.

when I try to use the `cabal repl` command I get
[image]

The error says it cannot find `plutus-ledger-api` which is in the cabal file.  If I comment out `plutus-ledger-api` then it does to the next one on the list of `build-depends`.  It is like I am missing a reference to something but I don't know where.  I think I am missing some information on how I actually get Plutus in my project.  I've built a cabal file for a standard haskell program without a problem and the cabal files in the pioneer program were already complete.  Confused on what to do.  Does anyone have any ideas?  Thanks.

Oh also as I note I copied the Utilities folder into my dapp from the pioneer program code as there was a lot of useful functions in there.  It is strange that file had its own cabal file as well.  Not sure if that is creating a problem as well.

Answer (score 2):

Someone mentioned something to me on the Cardano discord that I needed my `cabal.project` file.  I guess for some reason using `cabal init` doesn't put it in there?  Anyway, after I put that file in there and configured it everything built properly.

Comment: Yes, you will need a `cabal.project` file.